# Which RAM will be better?

Tags: imac, memory

Cheers! Which RAM will be better for my iMac 27" mid 2010 with i7 2.93GHz and MacOS 10.9.5:

[this](http://www.corsair.com/en-gb/corsair-mac-memory-16gb-dual-channel-ddr3-sodimm-memory-kit-cmsa16gx3m2a1333c9), [this](http://www.silicon-power.com/product/dram/tech/DDR3%20SODIMM%20Spec%20R15a.pdf) or ADATA DDR3 SO-DIMM 8GB 1333? Also I have saw Kignston KVR1333D3S9/8G but according to it data-sheet it works with 677MHz instead of 1333MHz (as I understood my iMac supports up to 32GB 1333 MHz PC3-10600 DDR3 SO-DIMMs with 204-pin). Which one is better?

Actually I want to get 20GB of RAM - 8GBx2 new plates + 2GBx2 of stock memory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Anything that matches the required spec should work. I've used Corsair and Kingston RAM without issue, and branding seems to be a somewhat personal preference. Most of the time, I get my [Mac RAM here](http://eshop.macsales.com/shop/memory/iMac/2010/DDR3_21.5_27) though and have never had issue.

Your aspiration for 20GB will be fine in your poroposed config.

Answer (score 0):

As said in the post before your config should work since it meets the specifications. 
One additional note: In order to leverage the dual channel capabilities of your RAM modules ensure that each pair is in a pair slot.

Different sized RAM pairs cant run in dual channel as far as I know.